# JSF and Ajax validation - How to update message panels for ALL messages?

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf-2, render

I want to do validate all input fields with AJAX.

For example, there are 3 input fields. Two of them require minimum length of 3 characters and the other is validated by a simple regex. For `<f:ajax>` I set up the keyup event to quickly see the ajax validation coming up. A complete example may look like this:

```
   <h:form>
       <h:messages id="messages" />
       <h:inputText id="text1" value="#{bean.text1}">
           <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
           <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="messages" />
       </h:inputText>

       <h:inputText id="text2" value="#{bean.text2}">
           <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
           <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="messages" />
       </h:inputText>

        <h:inputText id="text3" value="#{bean.text3}">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*" />
            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="messages" />
        </h:inputText>
    </h:form>
```

Once I leave the input first input field with an error and jump to the 2nd field and type invalid stuff there, the message from the first invalid field disappears, since the messages are rerendered! Setting execute to @form, will cause all fields to be validated, once I start typing within the first input field.

**So my question is:
How to display ALL validation errors with AJAX and not only the last message from the last invalid field?**

P.S.: Im using Mojarra 2.0.3 (+ Richfaces + Primefaces) on Websphere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible. Best what you can do is to just give each input their own message.

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:inputText id="text1" value="#{bean.text1}">
            <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
            <f:ajax event="keyup" render="text1message" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="text1message" for="text1" />

        <h:inputText id="text2" value="#{bean.text2}">
            <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
            <f:ajax event="keyup" render="text2message" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="text2message" for="text2" />

        <h:inputText id="text3" value="#{bean.text3}">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*" />
            <f:ajax event="keyup" render="text3message" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="text3message" for="text3" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

You can eventually group them together above the form.

Comment: thx for the fast answer, I marked it as correct. I will try to wrap the suggested functionality as a composite. the challenge will be to "collect" and group the IDs of each (input) component and link them within the message group on top of the page. Any suggestions/solutions on this? How are other people doing such things?